# About reactive ref([]) I don't understand vue3 composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I have make some side project to practice with vue.js.
The issue i encountered is behavior re-render of ref when it data changing.
I have a function to take new user info and update it record in array here is 3 version of code:

```
const listUserState = ref([]);

const saveEditUser = async (newUserInfor) => {
    const status = await fetchPost(api.editUser, newUserInfor[0]);
    if (status.status == true) {
        updateSuccess.value = true;
        listUserState.value.forEach(async (user, index) => {
            if (user.username == newUserInfor[0].user.username) {
                listUserState.value[index] = {};
                await nextTick();
                listUserState.value[index] = { ...newUserInfor[0].user };
            }
        });
    } else {
        updateSuccess.value = false;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        updateSuccess.value = null;
    }, 3000);
};

watch(listUserState.value, (newValue, oldValue) => {
console.log(newValue);
});
```

```
const listUserState = ref([]);

const saveEditUser = async (newUserInfor) => {
    const status = await fetchPost(api.editUser, newUserInfor[0]);
    if (status.status == true) {
        updateSuccess.value = true;
        listUserState.value.forEach(async (user, index) => {
            if (user.username == newUserInfor[0].user.username) {
                listUserState.value[index] = {};
                listUserState.value[index] = { ...newUserInfor[0].user };
            }
        });
    } else {
        updateSuccess.value = false;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        updateSuccess.value = null;
    }, 3000);
};

watch(listUserState.value, (newValue, oldValue) => {
console.log(newValue);
});
```

```
const listUserState = ref([]);

const saveEditUser = async (newUserInfor) => {
    const status = await fetchPost(api.editUser, newUserInfor[0]);
    if (status.status == true) {
        updateSuccess.value = true;
        listUserState.value.forEach(async (user, index) => {
            if (user.username == newUserInfor[0].user.username) {           
                listUserState.value[index] = { ...newUserInfor[0].user };
            }
        });
    } else {
        updateSuccess.value = false;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        updateSuccess.value = null;
    }, 3000);
};

watch(listUserState.value, (newValue, oldValue) => {
console.log(newValue);
});
```

I wondering that only version1.vue work fine and the was updated 2 other version 2 and 3 the DOM do not update. But when i logging for test change of `listUserState` all 3 version have logging data so I know all version work fine and the ref variable changed. But why only the version1.vue update the DOM .Although version2.vue and version3.vue `listUserState` also change but the DOM do not update.
I read on official document of vue they said:
[image]
I try to use splice method like this

```
// use splice for repalce two lines 
//listUserState.value[index] = {};
//listUserState.value[index] = { ...newUserInfor[0].user };

listUserState.value.splice(index,1,newUserInfor[0].user);
```

the `listUserState` variable still changed but not update the DOM. Only version1.vue update the DOM.
Is there something i misunderstand? Please help me and if you need more detail info please let me know.
Thank you <3

Comment: Is `listUserState` used in your template/DOM code? You've not shown this.  Also, I'm not sure what you mean that it works in Vue v1.  Compositon API didn't exist before Vue 3.  You would have to use very different code for older versions, which you've also not shown.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , the question can't be solved on its own, the snippet you posted depends on the other parts of the app.  It's unknown what happens with newUserInfor to the point await nextTick could make a difference. This suggests that there may be race conditions that aren't shown. `forEach(async` is a mistake, and `watch(listUserState.value` should be `watch(listUserState`

Comment: i mentioned 3 version of code below not version of vuejs